# ¿Por qué se llama "caravana" en Uruguay al aro en la oreja?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, uruguay

Acabo de descubrir que en Uruguay llaman *caravana* al aro en la oreja:

En el artículo [*Piercings: Oreja en su totalidad*](https://www.vix.com/es/btg/bodyart/2007-12-18/373/piercings-oreja-en-su-totalidad) explican:

> [image]
>
> Además de tener una caravana en el lugar típico, donde todos suelen perforarse, se puso un aro, dos pequeñas **caravanas** y a lo último estos Piercings que parecen ser dos por separado. ¡Pero no lo son!

Mirando en el DAMER me encuentro:

> [**caravana**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=caravana).
>
> I.    1.  f. Mx, Gu. Reverencia, inclinación del cuerpo en señal de respeto.
>
> II.   1.  f. Ur; Bo, Ar, Ur, obsol; Bo, p.u. Pendiente largo, generalmente de plata u oro, muy trabajado.
> 2.  Ar, Ur. Dispositivo de plástico a modo de broche o aro, normalmente de dos piezas que se acoplan, que se coloca a un animal en la oreja para identificarlo.

(Como curiosidad, marca su uso en Uruguay, pero que luego en ese país, Argentina y Bolivia sea obsoleto.)

Es curioso porque en España [*caravana*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7RODWYe) suele utilizarse tanto para definir un grupo que se desplaza (definición tradicional) como últimamente más para *Vehículo acondicionado para hacer vida en él, remolcado por un automóvil*. Sin embargo, el uso de esta palabra como *pendiente* me sorprende y no hallo explicaciones al respecto.

Por tanto, ¿por qué se usa caravana para designar al broche en la oreja? ¿Se usa?

Comment: No aparece Chile en la lista del DAMER, pero acá claro que existen las **carabanas** (yo solo lo he visto con b larga). Se compran en ferias artesanales. Son todas las joyas, como pulseras, collares y pendientes formadas por varias piedritas, una después de la otra. Ninguno de los de la foto lo es (en Chile).

Comment: @Rodrigo ahora que me fijo: ¿en Chile llamáis a la _b_ como _b larga_? ¿Es entonces la _v_ una _b corta_?

Comment: @fedorqui Supongo que en Chile es igual que en Uruguay, eso quiere decir:
b = be larga
v = be corta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La obra siguiente sugiere que viene así de la significación mexicana:

- ceremonias, cortesías → adornos colgantes > pendientes con adornos colgantes → pendientes

> El Diccionario de la lengua castellana introdujo la acepción caravanas, como pendientes, arracadas, propia de Argentina, Bolivia, Chile y Uruguay, en 1925. Corominas relaciona el término con ceremonias, cortesías, usual en México y Honduras, y como desarrollo posterior podrá considerarse caravanas, zarcillos, pendientes con adornos colgantes, usada en la Argentina, Chile, Bolivia y Perú...
>
> - [*Lo suntuario en la vida cotidiana del Buenos Aires virreinal: de lo material a lo espiritual*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8IDjAAAAMAAJ&q="caravanas"), Nelly Raquel Porro, Estela Rosa Barbero

Y antes que su primera aparición en la RAE, tenía esta definición:

> `amer. Mej.` Reverencia, cortesía, por lo común afectada.
>   `pl.` Las primeras campañas que hacían por mar los caballeros de Malta contra moros y piratas.
>
> `amer. Arg.` Zarcillos ó pendientes **con adornos colgantes.** *Bailarle la caravana á uno.*
>
> - [*Enciclopedia vniversal ilvstrada evropeo-americana*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1ZENAQAAMAAJ) Volume 11 (p.711) (1907)

Answer (score 0):

Así es, en Uruguay caravana se utiliza como termino de una joya para colgar, pegar en la oreja; Así como también el traslado de un grupo de personas en vehículo (autos, camiones, bicicletas, barcos, etc..).
La RAE no tiene todos los significados de cada palabra de cada país. La RAE se utiliza como apoyo para cambiar determinadas funciones del lenguaje, *pero solo como apoyo*, nadie tiene una verdad absoluta.